# Extract a subarray

Tags: c, lua

I have managed to transfer the 2d array int a 1d array to make it simpler. So given:

```
local table = {0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,0,30,31,32,33, 0,34,35,36,37, 0 }
```

How can I extract a sub-array as below?

```
local sub =  {2,3,4,7,8,9,12,13,14,17,18,19,22,23,24}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way...

```
> t = {}
> for i = 7, 30, 5 do
>>     for j = i, i + 2 do
>>         t[#t+1] = ble[j]
>>     end
>> end
> for k,v in ipairs(t) do print(k,v) end
1   2
2   3
3   4
4   7
5   8
6   9
7   12
8   13
9   14
10  17
11  18
12  19
13  22
14  23
15  24
>
```

I renamed your table to `ble` so it doesn't shadow the table library.

Comment: that's just brilliant. Thank you.